# what does this pattern mean? new (&entries[num_entries]) item;

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

code looks like below:

```
struct set_t {
       static const uint32 MAX_ENTRIES=128;
       uint32 num_entries;
       item_t entries[MAX_ENTRIES]; 

       inline void add_back(item_t item){
            ***new (&entries[num_entries]) item;***
            ++num_entries;
       }
```

};

This line:    "new (&entries[num_entries]) item;"  is puzzling, does it actually allocate memory?

Comment: Please tag this question as C++

Answer (score 1):

please have a look at this question : [What uses are there for "placement new"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new)

```
new (address) varname;
```

is the so called placement new operator, which constructs an object on a pre-allocated buffer.

So the answer to your question is: it does not allocate new memory.